# Firebase: how to get setValue to work properly

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
SGContainer multi = new SGContainer("MATH",212);
User charlie = new User("charlie","charlie","911911911","charlie@duke.edu", "password");
StudyGroup m212mid = new StudyGroup(charlie,"MATH",212,1.5,"Midterm Prep", 20);
multi.add(m212mid);
math212Ref.setValue(multi);
```

SGContainer has the following variables:

```
private String myCategory;
private String myName;
private int myNum;
private StudyGroup[] myGroups;
```

and myGoups is supposed to contain m212mid
Here's what happens on Firebase:

[image]

Why can't i see myGroups and m212mid?
I tried to make myGroups into an ArrayList and a HashMap but neither worked

Answer (score 0):

The objects did not adhere to POJO protocol, so once I made a simpler version of the class (one that only contained variables and a constructor), and wrote a method to convert from one to the other, I was able to upload the simpler POJO class on Firebase easily